# Modify Controls.Input width in websharper

Tags: input, controls, websharper

I tried to modify Controls.Input size in Websharper, by using Enhance.WithCssClass unsuccessfully. The max-length in the css was applied to the whole control, and not to the Input markup.

How can I apply different lengths to different Controls.Input controls?

Answer (score 1):

The CSS class indeed applies to the container. To style the actual input using `Enhance.WithCssClass "myClass"`, you need to apply the style to the `input` inside `myClass`:

```
.myClass input {
    width: 300px;
}
```